# Computation of confluent hypergeometric function 1F1 with complex arguments?

Tags: r

Is there a routine in R for computing the Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1(a,b,z)$ for complex arguments?

Comment: Which packages did you try? Did you look up CRAN Taskviews?

Comment: To maximize upvotes/minimize chance of closure, you might consider: (1) (echoing @kjetilbhalvorsen) explaining what you've tried so far and (2) reframing your question as much as possible as "how can I do xxx?" and not as "is there a routine to do xxx?" (which approaches the dreaded "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" question type ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`library("sos"); findFn("Kummer")` got me to the [hypergeometric functions from the fAsianOptions package](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/fAsianOptions/html/HypergeometricFunctions.html), specifically the `kummerM` function.

> ‘kummerM’     the Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the 1st Kind

> ...

> The functions use the TOMS707 Algorithm by M. Nardin, W.F. Perger
> and A. Bhalla (1989).  A numerical evaluator for the confluent
> hypergeometric function for complex arguments with large
> magnitudes using a direct summation of the Kummer series. The
> method used allows an accuracy of up to thirteen decimal places
> through the use of large real arrays and a single final division.

I have no idea what sensible inputs would be, but I can get *an* answer for complex values:

```
kummerM(x=1i, a=1i, b=1i)
## [1] 0.5403023+0.841471i
```

This agrees with the result from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric1F1%5BI%2C+I%2C+I%5D) ...

Edit: this package was deleted from CRAN. But it is still on GitHub: https://github.com/cran/fAsianOptions